# jquery.datepicker.js is working but no styling is shown by it

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have to use a datepicker to select a date in input text. So I used the jquery.datepicker.js

Now as I click on the calendar pic shown along with the input box, a calendar like thing appears on  **the very bottom of the page**  and also that calendar is **not using any styling or any css file** that I attach to my html page.

Please suggest me something that can help.

Apart from links to **datePicker.css** and **jquery.datePicker.js** that I found online, I have added this script in the head tag.

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datePicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
    });
```

The datepicker plugin that I am using, I got it from kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html

Comment: Might be a css conflict between the jquery ui css and your css

Comment: Without seeing your code, this is impossible to answer. Did you include one of the [jQueryUI themes](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery) or are you styling it yourself?

Comment: Please add a link to the datepicker plugin you are using.

Comment: The datepicker plugin that I am using, I got it from 
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah, the confusion in the question comments - which I was also thrown by - is that there is a standard jQueryUI plug-in called Datepicker, but that is not what you are using.

I'd say either your code is missing these lines or something equivalent from the kelvinluck examples:

```
<!-- datePicker required styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles/datePicker.css">
```

or the server doesn't find it, because the path is not correct or it simply isn't in that directory.